# Entity Framework 3.0 and Helper-classes

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using static helper classes in a class library for stuff like filtering out certain entities using LINQ. I pass the ObjectContext and the parameters I want to filter on. The problem is that the ObjectContext gets corrupted.

For instance:

```
Users u = EntityHelper.GetUsersOfCertainAge(ObjectContext, 24);
ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
```

The Users-list will be properly populated, but the program will crash upon `ObjectContext.SaveChanges()`, even though no changes have been made. I'm not able to save the changes at all, even in cases where changes have been made.

I'm getting "Null reference exception" and DateTime overflows etc. It seems an empty object ends up in the ObjectContext, so when I'm trying to save, it violates all kinds of constraints in the database. I don't know why though, all I'm doing inside the Helper-classes is to filter some list in the ObjectContext using LINQ and returning the results.

Do you guys know what could lead to this corruption, if the approach is plain wrong/bad or if there are good alternatives? Creating a new context afterword works, but it feels like a hack.

Example (stored in a separate class library, in a static class):

```
public static User GetFirstUserOfCertainAge(Entities ctx, int inputAge)
{
    return ctx.Users
        .Where(x => x.Age == inputAge)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with corrupted?

Comment: Sorry I'm a little tired. Clarified it, hopefully it helps!

Comment: Can you post the code for `GetUsersOfCertainAge()`?

Comment: I'd suggest posting the code of your method so people can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using something like this as an alternative as its cleaner:

```
public static IQueriable<User> FilterByAge(this IQueriable<User> users, int inputAge)
{
    return users
        .Where(x => x.Age == inputAge)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Created);
}
```

with useage:

```
User u = ctx.Users.FilterByAge(24).FirstOrDefault();
```

In terms of the error you are getting the method you are currently using should work just fine with EF( though the above is a bit more clean/fluent). My bet is that the issue is that your context scope isnt quite right. Can you post the bit where you get/dispose the context as well?

Comment: In a web control/endpoint, at the top of the class, I just create the context: private Entities ObjectContext = new Entities();

Comment: try putting it in a using block so its properly being disposed, again it probably wont solve the actual error youre getting but its using the framework correctly

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I created a test-user, and one of the test-users complex properties were fetched from the ObjectContext, which apparently led to this test-user indirectly also belonging to the ObjectContext (a little odd). When I saved, it also tried to save this test-user. Anyhow, making sure not to set any complex type relating to the ObjectContext in this test-users properties solved it.